# Could not find annotation-1.5.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, annotations

"Could not find annotation-1.5.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0). Searched in the following locations: [https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.5.0/annotation-1.5.0.jar"](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.5.0/annotation-1.5.0.jar%22)

My VPN is on and everything seems to be fine and I tried to run it on web and it works perfectly
how to fix this please